# How to fill a triangle using Graphics class (Java)

Tags: java

My goal is to be able to draw/fill in a triangle using the Graphics class. I was able to fill in/draw a rectangle & a circle but when I try to compile my code I get the error below.

I understand that the fill polygon method takes in type arrays but I don't know what other method to use other then .fillPologyon that takes in the parameters I want.

Is there another method that I didn't try? Is there a way to convert my width & height for my rttriangle while not messing up the code for drawing a rectangle.

```
DrawArea.java:62: error: no suitable method found for fillPolygon(int,int,int,int)
                    g.fillPolygon(100, 100, width, height);
                     ^
method Graphics.fillPolygon(int[],int[],int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Graphics.fillPolygon(Polygon) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  1 error

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DrawArea extends JComponent {
private int radius;
private int width; // base for rt trig
private int height;
//private int [] w = new int[]
//private int [] h = new int[];
private String shape;

/**
 * constructor for circle
 * @param shape string "circle"
 * @param r the radius the user entered
 */
public DrawArea(String shape, int r){
    this.shape = shape;
    radius = r;
}
/**
 * constructor for rectangle and right triangle
 * @param shape either the string "rectanlge" or "triangle"
 * @param w - either the width or the base
 * @param h - height of rect or tri
 */
public DrawArea(String shape, int w, int h){
    this.shape = shape;
    width = w;
    height = h;


}
/**
 * paint method that draws the selected shape
 */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ // Graphic g is and object allows you to set color to green
    removeAll();
    if(shape.equals("circle")){
        //Set color to green
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        // 100 pixels down 100 pixels over
        //How wide and how tall = radius *2 = diamter
        //There broth width and height
        g.fillOval(100, 100, radius * 2, radius * 2);   
    }else if(shape.equals("rectangle")){
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(100, 100, width, height);   //change  **************************************
    //}else{

    }else if(shape.equals("rtTriangle")){
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillPolygon(100, 100, width, height);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to define your triangle as a `Polygon` , and use [fillPolygon(Polygon)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon-java.awt.Polygon-) e.g:

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(40, 55);
triangle.addPoint(60, 55);
triangle.addPoint(50, 35);

g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillPolygon(triangle);
```

Now just use your `width` and `height` variables, to define the three points of the triangle as you need.

Here is an example of the points you could use :

```
triangle.addPoint(0, height); // bottom-left angle
triangle.addPoint(width, height); // bottom-right angle
triangle.addPoint(width / 2, 0); // top angle
```

[image]

Comment: Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
  triangle.addPoint(width,height);
  g.setColor(Color.green);  
  g.fillPolygon(triangle);    
  //g.fillPolygon(100, 100, width, height);

Comment: So I tried this by putting the above code under the else if(shape.equals("rtTriangle")){ }

Comment: But the triangle still does not appear or is filled.

Comment: It is a triangular shape, it needs 3 points not just 1, or it won't even be a valid shape . Each point is the position of an angle of the triangle .

Comment: I don't see what you mean?

Comment: How do I use all three .addPoints(in width, int height) if I only have width and height to feed in as an argument.

Comment: Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(width,height);
triangle.addPoint(width,height);
triangle.addPoint(width,height);
g.setColor(Color.green);  
g.fillPolygon(triangle);

Comment: Is this what you want me to do?

Comment: when I do the above code it still does not work for me.

Comment: Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(0, height); // bottom-left angle
triangle.addPoint(width, height); // bottom-right angle
triangle.addPoint(width / 2, 0); // top angle
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillPolygon(triangle);

Comment: I added that and I'm still unable to see my outputted triangle

Comment: int x1 = 100; 
  int y1 = 100;
  int x2 = 100;
  int y2 =  100  + height;
  int x3 =  100 + width;
  int y3 = 100 + height; 
  int[]x = {x1,x2,x3};
  int[]y = {y1,y2,y3};
  g.setColor(Color.green);
  Polygon p = new Polygon(x,y,3);
  g.fillPolygon(p);

Comment: I fixed! The solution to my problem is the code above :)